# Puppet and hiera,how to apply changes?

Tags: puppet, hiera

I  want to update cron via puppet.
Until today i have used only foreman for apply
and never userd hiera.
Following this [howto](http://geek-kb.com/install-puppet-foreman-centos-6-x)
First i have create dirs for hiera

```
cd /etc/puppet && mkdir -p hieradata/development hieradata/production/domains hieradata/production/fqdns hieradata/production/OBSOLETE hieradata/production/roles
```

Then I edit hiera.yaml

```
:backends:
  - yaml :yaml: :datadir: '/etc/puppet/hieradata/%{::environment}' :hierarchy:
- fqdns/%{::fqdn}
- roles/%{::role}
- domains/%{::domain}
- common
```

Then I put in common.yaml

```
## Cron module
cron::enable: true     # on startup
cron::ensure: true     # running
cron::crontab_path: /etc/crontab
puppetheader: Managed by Puppet @ site.priv

cron::crontab_vars_hsh:
  SHELL: /usr/bin/sh
  PATH: /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
  MAILTO: ""
  HOME: /root

cron::crontab_site_job_hsh:
  'check scripts in cron.hourly, cron.daily, cron.weekly and cron.monthly': 
    - "*/35   *  *  *  *  script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1"
```

Hiera seems to work

hiera -c ../hiera.yaml   cron::ensure

```
hiera cron::ensure 
true
```

But after did puppet agent -t...nothing change
and /etc/crontab is system default.
I did also

```
puppet apply -e 'include cron' --hiera_config=/etc/puppet/hiera.yaml  --verbose --debug
```

and return

```
Debug: Scope(Class[Cron::Crontab::Config]): Retrieving template cron/crontab.erb
Debug: template[/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/cron/templates/crontab.erb]: Bound template variables for /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/cron/templates/crontab.erb in 0.00 seconds
Warning: Variable access via 'puppetheader' is deprecated. Use '@puppetheader' instead. template[/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/cron/templates/crontab.erb]:1
   (at /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/parser/templatewrapper.rb:77:in `method_missing')
Error: Failed to parse template cron/crontab.erb:
  Filepath: /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/parser/templatewrapper.rb
  Line: 82
  Detail: Could not find value for 'package_name' at /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/cron/templates/crontab.erb:2
 at /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/cron/manifests/init.pp:47 on node server.example.com
Error: Failed to parse template cron/crontab.erb:
  Filepath: /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/parser/templatewrapper.rb
  Line: 82
  Detail: Could not find value for 'package_name' at /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/cron/templates/crontab.erb:2
 at /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/cron/manifests/init.pp:47 on node centos.example.com
```

What i miss?

edit1: i add the .erb

```
## <%= puppetheader %>
# for <%= package_name %>

<% if (!crontab_vars_hsh.empty?)  -%>
## Variables
<% crontab_vars_hsh.sort.each do |key,val| -%>
<%= key %>=<%= val %> 
<% end -%>
<% end -%>

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * username command-to-be-executed

<% if (!crontab_site_job_hsh.empty?)  -%>
## Site Wide Jobs
<% crontab_site_job_hsh.sort.each do |key,val| -%>

# <%= key %>
<% val.each do |croncmd|  -%>
 <%= croncmd %>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>

<% if (!crontab_node_job_hsh.empty?)  -%>
## Node Specific Jobs
<% crontab_node_job_hsh.sort.each do |key,val| -%>

# <%= key %>
<% val.each do |croncmd|  -%>
 <%= croncmd %>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: It looks like your cron/crontab.erb file is broken, Can you post that? It looks like it needs a variable named "package_name" in your manifest

Comment: `package_name` isn't in your hiera and it is a required parameter is what that error is telling me

Comment: Also, just to add, I believe you need to restart the puppetserver service whenever you update your hiera stuff.

Comment: Restarted,nothing change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cron type**

[cron](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/types/cron.html) was a Puppet generic type up to Puppet 5, there's no need to install special module. For Puppet 6 and later [`cron_core` module](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/cron_core) is needed (the resource was moved to external module), e.g.

```
puppet module install puppetlabs-cron_core
```

The usage should be the same.

```
cron { 'myscript':
  command => '/usr/bin/python myscript.py',
  user    => 'root',
  minute  => '30',
  hour    => '0',
}
```

If you want to use Hiera yaml, declare some jobs

```
cron_jobs:
  'myscript':
    command: 'm/usr/bin/python myscript.py'
    minute: 30
    hour: 0
    date: '*'
    month: '*'
    weekday: '*'
    user: root
```

in Puppet code:

```
create_resources (cron, lookup('cron_jobs', Hash, undef, {}))
```

**Cron module**

[`cron` module](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-cron) doesn't internally use Puppet's `cron` type, it manages directly configuration files on disk. Thus the API could be slightly different:

```
---
cron::job:
  'myscript':
    command: 'm/usr/bin/python myscript.py'
    minute: 30
    hour: 0
    date: '*'
    month: '*'
    weekday: '*'
    user: root
```

and don't forget to add `include cron` somewhere to node's definition.